# Lombok not working Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, annotations, lombok, android-studio-3.0, intellij-lombok-plugin

I want to use Lombok in one of my projects in android studio 3.0 and I have problems with it. Annotations work fine and they don't have any errors. 
Here are my Gradle dependencies which I added Lombok in it.

```
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
```

I have a problem with `Annotation Processors` too. 
I have followed these steps:

- in `file>other settings>default settings` i have enabled the `Annotation Processors`
- I have `Invalidate Caches / Restart`
- in the `project settings` suddenly the `Annotation Processors` settings appeared under the `Build, Execution, Deployment>Compiler` menu which it was not there before `Invalidating Cache` and I check its tick.
- I have installed the Lombok plugin

when the Android Studio restarts the `Annotation Processors` setting is gone but the plugin doesn't show any errors.

After doing all this still it doesn't work.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import lombok.Getter;

class UserModel {

    @SerializedName("uid")
    @Getter private String userId;


}
```

this is how I defined my model and cant get the getUserId out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue for me. Android Studio 3.2 default config.

-Installed Lombok plugin
-Added the following to app dependencies
`compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'`

And Lombok annotations were just ignored. After restarting Android Studio I got the Event log saying Lombok requires annotation processing, but Preferences/ Build Exec.../Compiler didn't show anything under it.

File / Invalidate caches restart did the trick. After that I could see the annotation processors option.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this after doing the works above I restarted my pc and suddenly everything was working allright